# Running a simulation file in Gatling in Mac

Tags: automated-tests, load, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm a a novice with Gatling.

I'm running my 1st test on Mac

1. I've open the recorder in one terminal
2. I've created a .har file
3. I've opened user-file in another in another terminal.
4. I'm trying to run subl RecordedSimulation.scala

I'm getting an error message:

```
zsh: command not found: subl
```

I've also done a video for clarity [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9adw7sl4roz3b4/GatlingRecorderQuestion.mov?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

This has really nothing to do with Gatling.

`subl` is the executable for [Sublime Text Editor](https://www.sublimetext.com/) which is simply the text editor the author of the Udemy course you've subscribed uses. You just don't have it (in your path).

Use whatever text editor suites you.

Comment: That's really odd as I actually do have sublime text editor.  I wonder why it  still didn't open?

Comment: You need to configure Sublime text to work from the command line, check this post - https://olivierlacan.com/posts/launch-sublime-text-3-from-the-command-line/